# Unable to provide a default value as NOW() for 'datetime' column while creating table in ClearDB on azure

Tags: mysql, azure, cleardb

I got an error while trying to set a **datetime** column a default value **NOW()** or **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**:

```
ALTER TABLE temp MODIFY COLUMN EntryDate EntryDate datetime DEFAULT NOW()
```

Primarily, the same query worked perfectly on a local instance on MySQL but while firing the same query on ClearDB on Azure it did not work. It would flag an error saying invalid default value for EntryDate.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this one?